# Using logs to find numerical values

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> If $\frac{log(a)}{log(b)}=1000,$ then what is the numerical value of $\frac{log(a/b)}{log(b)}$?

I was not sure on how to solve this. I was just looking at this problem to see how would you solve it. I tried doing this but I don't see how you can get a numerical value from this compared to other problems:

$\frac{log(b)*1000}{log(a)}$

Can someone please help me with this solution?

Comment: Do you know any ways to rewrite $\log(a/b)$? If not, what about $\log(ab)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the laws of logs.

$\log(\frac ab) = \log a - \log b$

So the expression becomes $\frac{\log a - \log b}{\log b} = \frac{\log a}{\log b} - 1$ which equals $999$.

Comment: Thank you. I thought about doing it that way but ended up cross multiplying and got confused with the $log(a/b)$ in the parenthesis compared to log(a)/log(b). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that $\log(a/b)=\log a-\log b$. Then

$$\frac{\log(a/b)}{\log b}=\frac{\log(a)}{\log b}-1.$$